# Firebase Prevent Creating Account Before Email Verification

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am working on an android project that includes user sign-in with email. But the problem is this. ***When I create test account it immediately appears in the firebase authentication section without verification***. But it also sends verification mail. I want to prevent this. Because for example if somebody enters my email address and they can not click verification link because it comes to my mailbox. But when I try to sign-up with my normal mail address app crashes and it is not sending verification mail again. ***My goal is to prevent account creating without verification and sending verification email on second or third or whatever try.***

Comment: could you explain this part _Because for example if somebody enters my email address and they can not click verification link because it comes to my mailbox. But when I try to sign-up with my normal mail address app crashes and it is not sending verification mail again_

Comment: it is just a scenario. for example my mail address is sample1@gmail.com   my friend know my mail address but he doesn't know password. he can enter my mail address just for prank and when i enter my mail address for registerin i can not register because he put the password. i want to prevent this

Answer (score 1):

If you require only verified accounts, then you should enforce it via security rules.

```
"$uid": {
  ".read": "auth != null && auth.uid == $uid && auth.token.email_verified === true",
  ".write": "auth != null && auth.uid == $uid && auth.token.email_verified === true"
}
```

If you don't like that the account was created and discarded, you can write an offline job using the [Firebase Admin SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users) to clean up unverified accounts after some time.

You can't verify the email before creating the account.

Comment: i did not say can i verify the email before creating account. at firebase console it appears immediately after registering process. i want to prevent this. i want to see them on the firebase console after verification process