# How to add Email Authentication with Firebase in Flutter Application?

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication, email-verification

I am creating an app where the user has to signup with an Email and Password. I want firebase to first verify the email if it does exist and it is an email and sends a link to the user to verify the email after this creates the account in firebase. So how can I do it can anyone tell me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been covered quite a few times before, so I'll provide some links below. The bottom line is that the [Firebase email+password provider](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/password-auth) provides no way to require email verification before account creation. The closest it has to that is the [email link provider](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/email-link-auth), which sends an email that signs the user into an account (without entering a password).

Some previous questions on the topic:

- [Verify a user's email address before confirming registration, with Flutter and Firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60280970/verify-a-users-email-address-before-confirming-registration-with-flutter-and-f/60283684#60283684)
- [Firebase email verification at SignUp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48028927/firebase-email-verification-at-signup/48029049#48029049)
- [How to prevent user authentication in Firebase/Vue.js BEFORE email is verified](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56780964/how-to-prevent-user-authentication-in-firebase-vue-js-before-email-is-verified/56784168#56784168)
- [more...](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bfirebase-authentication%5D+require+email+verification+before+sign-in)