# Firebase - Freeze an account until email is verified

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

I want to maintain an account disabled until it passes the email verification.

Problem is, as a user registers itself via `createUserWithEmailAndPassword`, the newly created account is ready to be used.
The only way I can avoid authentication is to check email verification flag via js in client app and deny login, but I don't want to rely on client controls, I'd prefer that firebase itselfs deny the authentication until email is verified.

Is there a way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can (and should) also check if the email is verified in the back-end, either:

- in security rules, if you're using Firestore, Realtime Database, or Storage
- in your own backend code, using a Firebase Admin SDK

When you do this, the client-side check is nothing more than a way to show the correct UI for the current state ("hey there, your email isn't verified yet. Check your inbox, or click here to resend the email"). It's the server-side check that controls access to the data, which is precisely how you want it to be.

This has been covered quite regularly before, so also see:

- the Firebase documentation on [implementing role-based access control on Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/role-based-access)
- [How do I lock down Firebase Database to any user from a specific (email) domain?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36943350/how-do-i-lock-down-firebase-database-to-any-user-from-a-specific-email-domain) (for Realtime Database)
- [Only let pre-verified users log into Firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57343031/only-let-pre-verified-users-log-into-firebase)